# Mysql replication, master_log_pos sync but tables not update

Tags: mysql-replication

First, my replication config on Master:

```
server-id = 1
replicate-same-server-id = 0
auto-increment-increment = 1
auto-increment-offset = 1
log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days = 5
binlog_format = mixed
max_connections=500
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5G
tmpdir=/mnt/data_mysql/mysql_tmp
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql_log/slow_query.log
slow_query_log = OFF
long_query_time = 50
sync_binlog = 1
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
```

On Slave:

```
server-id = 73
replicate-same-server-id = 0
replicate-do-db=rep_1624
auto-increment-increment = 1
auto-increment-offset = 1
#slave-skip-errors = 1062
binlog_format = mixed
long_query_time = 50
expire_logs_days  = 5
```

All tables use InnoDB.When I start the slave, it works good, IO and SQL are running, bin cursor increases correctly but some tables are not synced. There is no error in mysql log.Tables are more then 1GB in size.

Slave Status :

```
Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: report.****
                  Master_User: replica
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.004153
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 96627039
               Relay_Log_File: slave-relay.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 10486693
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.004153
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: rep_1624
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 96627039
              Relay_Log_Space: 10486862
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: baeb9b03-c1a3-11e4-b6e1-220b8ecd7e
             Master_Info_File: /mnt/data_mysql/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```